# Consider $x^5-2x+1$ and $4x+1$. Then for any $c \in \mathbb{Z}_5$, we have

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Shalom. I'm having a bit of trouble seeing where the following "congruences" are coming from:

> $c^5-2c+1 \equiv -c +1 \equiv 4c+1 \mod{5}$.

I see why they're congruent (by testing the values of $\mathbb{Z}_5$), but I'm unable to see how $c^5-2c+1 \equiv -c+1 \mod 5$ and $-c +1 \equiv 4c+1 \mod{5}$ came about. (The author of the abstract algebra book I'm following only introduced Fermat's little theorem and a little bit about linear congruence.) Any further explanation is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first congruence is due to Fermat's Little Theorem:

$$c^5 \equiv c \pmod 5$$

Thus $c^5-2c+1 \equiv c-2c+1\equiv -c+1 \pmod 5$.

The second congruence is due to divisibility:

$$5c \equiv 0 \pmod 5$$

Thus $-c+1 \equiv -c+5c+1 \equiv 4c + 1 \pmod 5$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Fermat's little theorem says if $c \not \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ then $c^4 \equiv 1$ and $c^5 \equiv c \pmod 5$.

So $c^5 - 2c +1 \equiv c - 2c +1 \equiv -c + 1 \pmod 5$.

And as $4\equiv -1 \pmod 5$ we have $4c + 1 \equiv -c + 1\pmod 5$.

So $c^5 - 2c +1\equiv -c + 1\pmod 5 \equiv 4c + 1 \pmod 5$.

That's all there is to it.

*BUT* you have to accept $c^5 \equiv c \pmod 5$.  Can you accept that?  (It's okay to say, no, this is new and you don't quite get it yet.)

Comment: I can accept it -- much appreciated!

Comment: Get used to FLT.  You are going to use it.... a lot.